# Best method to identify the reason for an [Authorize] policy failure?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Without creating custom authorization handlers, is there a way in asp.net core to detect the reason that an action fails with a 401 Unauthorized and return a semantically helpful response?

Specific example: User has the role "Student". Action has an attribute specifying [Authorize(Roles = "Teacher")]. When User attempts to load Action, a policy failure results in an error view being redirected to via the authentication middleware.

Ideally I would be able to identify the reason within the error handling action method and provide a specific response stating that the requested URL is only available for Teachers, but so far nothing obvious has presented itself. I can identify which authentication schemes were involved, and which roles the user is in, but it's unclear if I can tell which roles are required for the action.

Comment: I like this question . However , it seems that there's no best method to achieve that goals for the present . The ASP.NET Core team is considering to make an improvement for this scenario .  See [a dirty hack here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/699) , and [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1560) and [discussion here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1359)